# jquery hide label and text that called from DB

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a problem about hiding label and data that shown from database after select . Because in my table , i have a lot column so if i call them all , it will be a lot of null data. To avoid the null data , i want to hide the them when display data.
**show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <b>Category:</b>
  <%= @combine.master.category if @combine.master %>
</p>

<p id="type">
  <b>Type:</b>
  <%= @combine.type %>
</p>

<p id="project">
  <b>Project name:</b>
  <%= @combine.project_name %>
</p>

<p id="unit">
  <b>Unit no:</b>
  <%= @combine.unit_no %>
</p>

<p id="block">
  <b>Block no:</b>
  <%= @combine.block_no %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Road name:</b>
  <%= @combine.road_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Level:</b>
  <%= @combine.level %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Facing:</b>
  <%= @combine.facing %>
</p>

<p>
  <b id="tc">Size:</b>
  <%= @combine.size %>
</p>

<p id="value">
  <b>Value:</b>
  <%= @combine.value %>
</p>

<p id="match">
  <b>Match bank:</b>
  <%= @combine.match_bank %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Asking:</b>
  <%= @combine.asking %>
</p>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#combine_category_id").val() == 1){
        $("#type").hide();
        $("#block").show();
        $("#level").show();
        $("#tc").text('Size');
        $("#value").hide();
        $("#project").show();
        $("#unit").hide();
        $("#match").show();
    }
        else if ($("#combine_category_id").val() == 3){
        $("#type").hide();
        $("#block").hide();
        $("#road").show();
        $("#level").hide();
        $("#facing").show();
        $("#size").show();
        $("#tc").text('Land size');
        $("#value").hide();
        $("#asking").show();
        $("#project").hide();
        $("#unit").show();
        $("#match").show();
    }
        else if ($("#combine_category_id").val() == 2){
        $("#type").show();
        $("#block").show();
        $("#road").show();
        $("#level").show();
        $("#facing").show();
        $("#size").show();
        $("#tc").text('Size');
        $("#value").show();
        $("#asking").show();
        $("#project").hide();
        $("#unit").hide();
        $("#match").hide();
    }
 });
```

Hope for anyone to help me solve this problem
Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need javascript for that?

What about doing something like:

```
<%- unless @combine.type.blank? %>
  <p>
    <b>Type:</b>
    <%= @combine.type %>
  </p>
<%- end %>
```

And so on for the rest of the fields? You can also write a iteration to avoid writing repetitive code:

```
<%- %w(type project unit block road_lavel name facing).each do |col| %>
  <%- unless @combine.send(col).blank? %>
    <p>
      <b><%= col.humanize %>:</b>
      <%= @combine.send(col) %>
    </p>
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

or put that code within a helper as well